# PHPMailer returning 500: Internal server error from a hosted website

Tags: php, smtp, apache2, phpmailer

I am trying to learn web development.
I bought a domain name say "test.com" and have hosted it.

I am trying to implement a feature to send emails from the website.

A particular php file on the server looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once "Mail.php";

$from = '<xyz.gmail.com>';
$to = '<xyz@abc.com>';
$subject = 'Hi!';
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

$headers = array(
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
    'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => '465',
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'somePassowrd'
));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
} else {
    echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
}

?>
```

The email is also sent if I run the code from my PC's terminal.

From my PC, accessing localhost/testemail.php or 0.0.0.0/testemail.php also successfully sends an email.

Now if I ssh into the computer (Ubuntu 14.04 server) where the files are hosted and run "php testemail.php" then the email is successfully sent.

Finally I also tried making a url call from the server's terminal using:
xdg-open http://localhost/testemail.php
and even in that case I receive an email on xyz@abc.com

However, from the browser making test.com/testemail.php results in 500 Internal Server Error.

I have tried hitting test.com/someotherfile.php?somequeryparams and get expected response. So the server is running fine, but sending emails is not working.

Please suggest what I can do.

Thank you.

Comment: A 500 error will generate an entry in the PHP/Apache error log. Best check that first.

Comment: No, cannot find anything useful in php/apache error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that on running the php code was not able to access the pear packages when called from an external browser.
I added the location to pear in the apache2 and the php include paths.

This fixed it.